# creating a object that contains an array of numbers to then store in a vector c++

Tags: c++

so i have a class named numbers which takes an array of numbers and shuffles them and then print out the new array.

what i would like to do is then return the new array as a object and push back that object in a vector of type "numbers".
 here is my code:

```
  class numbers
{
    private:

    static int indexCount;
    //vector <vector <int> > list;
    //vector<int> temp;
    int j;

   public:

    void swap (int *a, int *b)  
    {  
      int temp = *a;  
      *a = *b;  
      *b = temp;  
    }  

    int randomize (int arr[], int n)  
    {  
      indexCount=0;

      for (int i = n -1; i > 0; i--)  
      {   
        j = rand() % (i + 1); 
        indexCount++;
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);  

      } 

    }
void printArray (int arr[], int n)  
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    cout << "random calls: " << indexCount <<endl; 

}  
};
```

and here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    vector <numbers> list;
    srand (time(NULL));  
    numbers num;
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0};  
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    num.randomize(arr,n);
    num.printArray(arr,n);
    list.push_back(num);
  return 0;
}
```

the code works fine but what i am trying to do is get the randomised numbers and store it in my object ie:
num = randomize(arr,n)
and then i can pushback num into list.
then when i print out my vector it contains the list of numbers

any idea how i can do this

Answer (score -1):

Well, couple hints on stdib:  std::swap, std::sort, std::shuffle (example):

```
std::shuffle(tmp_buffer.begin(), tmp_buffe.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device()()));
```

Random in range [a;b) example:

```
template <class T = float>
inline T uniformRandom(T low = static_cast<T>(0.), T hi = static_cast<T>(1.))
{
    static_assert (std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "T must be floating point one.");
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(low, hi);
    return dis(gen);
}
```

So you don't need any extra class actually. You can have numeric vector and use std functions on that.
Well, if you really want a class, just put that vector and calls to stdlib in that new class ...